# NSFilemanager doesn't save file when textFieldDidEndEditing is called a second time

Tags: ios, ipad, file, uitableview, reload

I am having trouble with updating my `tableView`.

In the tableView of the popover managed by the `rootviewcontroller`, some items in my documents directory are displayed. In the `detailViewcontroller`, i change the names of those files by using the `NSFilemanager`. Regardless what I do, the tableView won't display the new ones. I get to see them if i close the app and open it again. At the moment, i try using notifications, but it doesn't work …

**EDIT**

I logged my documents directory, its definitely not a tableView problem, moreover, it works out well, but the second time I enter some text, nothing happens…

### DetailViewController

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)tf
{
    textLabel.text = textField.text;
    NSString* newName = textLabel.text;
    newName = [newName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];
    NSString* newPath = [[currentFilePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newName]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",newPath);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:currentFilePath toPath:newPath error:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataSaved" object:nil];

}
```

### RootViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataSaved:) name:@"DataSaved" object:nil];
}

- (void)dataSaved:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self loadDirectoryContents];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Oh loadDirectoryContents works well btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works out when I type in something. But if i type in something the second time without having anything selected in the tableView, the fileManager doesn't move the item to the path. Any suggestions? It doesnt seem to be a tableView related Problem.

I also thought I needed to set:

```
currentFilePath = newPath;
```

But that gave me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: I needed to retain: `[currentFilePath retain];`

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tableView initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

This line looks a bit suspicious. How are you constructing your tableview?

Comment: I am doing it programmatically. So also using tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath. The Table View works well. When I open and close the app, its also updated. But I want to have it updated immediately ;)

Comment: Are you also using UITableViewController, or have you created a nib file? The line I mentioned doesn't make sense unless you have already initialised your tableView somewhere else. Where is [UITableView alloc] in your code?

Comment: tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; //this is what i would expect to see if you had created your table solely programmatically

Comment: I just created a new project with the split view template. There isn't any UITableView, so you must have added this. Did you add it to DefaultView.xib ?

Comment: When I opened up the template and build run, in potrait mode, there is a button in the toolbar (left, top corner) which says "Events". If you click on it, an popup with the title "Root View Controller" opens up. In the pop up, there is an empty table view. In the class RootViewController there is also a bunch of tableView methods. Oh, and that initWithFrame stuff was added by me as I wanted the tableView to have the grouped style.